# Wordpress - Automatic category for a Custom Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I've created two new CPTs called 'Movie Reviews' and "Game Reviews". In my website I also have one category called 'Reviews' where you can find two sub-categories: 'Movie Reviews' and 'Game Reviews'.

I saw that I can set a specific taxonomy for each CPT, but what I want is to automaticly set one specific category to every post in this CPT. For example, if I write a movie review in my CPT 'Movie Reviews', I want to automaticly set the category of this post as 'Reviews' - 'Movie Reviews', because every post under this CPT will be like that.

Is this possible?

Comment: Sure, you could do it in a post save hook...but what's the real purpose? Being a CPT already distinguishes these posts.

Comment: It's because of some appearance tweaks and to show them properly in my menu. I'm kinda new in wordpress development so maybe this is a dumb idea :P

Comment: Custom post types can be targeted with custom templates. I recommend going that route.